# Trying to upload slightly bigger files using XMLHttpRequest result in POST http://.... 404 (Not Found) and http://... blocked by CORS policy

Tags: javascript, html, rest, cors, xmlhttprequest

I got a simple XMLHttpRequest that simply allow user to upload xml files from a webpage to a server. It is something like this

```
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append("thefile", file);
xmlhttprequest.send(formData);
```

and my rest server is something like this to receive the call

```
[HttpPost, Route("api/v1/workaroundtemplates/upload")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> ExecuteFileUpload()
{
    IHttpActionResult res;

    try
    {
        var httpRequest = HttpContext.Current.Request;
        var requestedFiles = new List<System.IO.Stream>();

        if (httpRequest.Files.Count > 0)
        {
            HttpFileCollection files = httpRequest.Files;
            //do things
            res = Ok();
        }
        else
            res = BadRequest();

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        mLog.Error(ex, "Failed to execute action");
        res = InternalServerError(ex);
    }

    return res;
}
```

This worked fine when I am uploading small files. However when I am uploading files that are slightly bigger like 50 MB I get the following error happening in my browser console and it looks as if the request never even made it to the server.

```
POST http://localhost:1062/api/v1/workaroundtemplates/upload 404 (Not Found)
folder-package-list:1 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:1062/api/v1/workaroundtemplates/upload' 
from origin 'http://localhost:1348' has been blocked by CORS policy: 
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

I tried to add this to my request header:

```
xmlhttprequest.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
xmlhttprequest.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,PUT,POST,DELETE");
```

this did not work the same error still persists. What is puzzling to me is that smaller files upload just fine. It is only the files that are bigger have this issue.

Does anyone know the cause for this? I have the freedom of changing either server or client side to allow this to work.

Comment: Note: the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` and `Access-Control-Allow-Methods` headers need to be set on the _response_, not the request.

Comment: so it should be setResponseHeader? I am not even sure that I can set response header in XMLHttpRequest
However the request failed to even reach the server all together when it is a bigger file. I am assuming it is some kind of preflight check that mess up my request. 
Would that even help with it?

Comment: 1) You need to set the response headers from the server, not the client. 2) Allowing the `OPTION` HTTP method should resolve the preflight issue you're getting.

Comment: sorry I am very new to this. Allowing the OPTION HTTP method is that done on server or client. Can you make an example? 
Thanks

Comment: What server language are you using? Is that c#?

Comment: If so, try adding `Response.AppendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");` and `Response.AppendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS");` whenever sending a successful response to the client.

Comment: Also, take a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/33399267/1911755

Comment: Yes it is c# on rest api, and JavaScript/polymer on front end I'll try it out and see if it works

Comment: you are right Raphael. It is the problem with the web.config not setting additional size

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what is going on it has nothing to do with CORS policy. It is basically my web service in the web.config did not have the setting

```
<configuration>
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="1048576" />
</system.web>
</configuration>


<system.webServer>
  <security>
     <requestFiltering>
     <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1073741824" />
      </requestFiltering>
   </security>
 </system.webServer>
```

However the error message thrown on the frontend of the page is extremly confusing and not helpful at all and led me onto the wrong path