# How to fix cross-source resource sharing (CORS) when uploading large files

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, file-upload, large-files

Small files are uploaded normally. However, a CORS error occurs when uploading large files. We set the capacity for uploading large files to the API, and also set the CORS. What is causing the error? Please let me know if there is anything I need to check further.

web.config files

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
 <system.web>
  <!-- ~ 4GB -->
  <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" executionTimeout="2400" maxRequestLength="2147483647" />
  <deployment retail="true" />
  <compilation debug="false" />
 </system.web>
<system.webServer>
  <security>
    <requestFiltering>
    <!-- ~ 4GB -->
    <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="4294967295" />
  </requestFiltering>
</security>
<handlers>
  <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
</handlers>
<aspNetCore requestTimeout="10:00:00" processPath="%LAUNCHER_PATH%" arguments="%LAUNCHER_ARGS%" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" forwardWindowsAuthToken="false">
  <environmentVariables>
    <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" value="Development" />
    <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT" value="44320" />
    <environmentVariable name="COMPLUS_ForceENC" value="1" />
  </environmentVariables>
</aspNetCore>
</system.webServer>
<runtime>
  <gcAllowVeryLargeObjects enabled="true" />
</runtime>
</configuration>
```

startup.cs files

```
services.AddCors(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy("SmartWorkApi",
            builder =>
            {
                builder
                    .AllowAnyOrigin()
                    .AllowAnyMethod()
                    .AllowAnyHeader(); 
            });
    });
```

Error message
" Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://~~~~' from origin 'https://~~~~' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."

Comment: Please check the Large file size and the IIS maxAllowedContentLength Configuration, make sure the Max allowed content Length in your web.config and the IIS configuration are set high enough. Here is a [similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33399267/cors-error-when-uploading-larger-files), you could check it.

Comment: @ZhiLv-MSFT As you can see above, it is set. It doesn't go over 2GB.

Comment: You can try to install [CORS extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/cors-module/cors-module-configuration-reference#cors-preflight-request) in IIS server, and check if it can respond to the preflight request correctly.